# Abort map execution in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

How can I break the map job in spark:

```
val rddFiltered = rdd.map(value => value.toInt).map(value => {

  if (value == 0)
  // if the condition is true , 
  // stop the map execution and return the processed RDD
  value
})
```

Suppose my rdd is  : `3,4,7,1,3,0,4,6`

I want `3,4,7,1,3`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not really something that you can efficiently solve using Spark. Order in which partitions are processed is not guaranteed and there is no such thing as partial transformation.

If you'd expect that expected number of records is small enough to be handled by the driver you could implement a similar method to `take` by iteratively `runJob` and collect the partitions as long you won't find the first one which contains a value which satisfy the predicate.

Alternatively, at the cost of a full data scan:

```scala
def takeWhile[T : ClassTag](rdd: RDD[T])(pred: T => Boolean) = {
  /* Determine partition where the predicate is not satisfied
     for the first time */
  val i = rdd.mapPartitionsWithIndex((i, iter) => 
    if (iter.exists(!pred(_))) Iterator(i) else Iterator()
  ).min

  /* Process partitions dropping elements after the first one
     which doesn't satisfy the predicate */
  rdd.mapPartitionsWithIndex { 
    case (j, iter) if j < i => iter  // before i-th take all elements

    // i-th drop after the element of interest
    case (j, iter) if j == i => iter.takeWhile(pred) 

    case _ =>  Iterator() // after i-th drop all
  }
}


val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(3, 4, 7, 1, 3, 0, 4, 6))

takeWhile(rdd)(_ != 0).collect
// Array[Int] = Array(3, 4, 7, 1, 3)

takeWhile(rdd)(_ != 3).collect
// Array[Int] = Array()

takeWhile(rdd)(_ >= 2).collect
// Array[Int] = Array(3, 4, 7)
```

Please note that this doesn't modify the number of partitions so without repartitioning it might result in a suboptimal resource utilization.

At the end of the day applying this type of sequential logic to Spark rarely makes sense. Also not that it doesn't modify the number of partitions so

Comment: It seems that the OP wants to deal with the data in some predefined order. The dataset should be scanned in that order, till the predicate is satisfied. If that's the case, this won't work. Also, why did you use `Iterator(i)` instead of, say, list? Since all we care about is the minimum partition number (which again assumes that the partition number that's lower is supposed to be the first in the OP's order, if any). Good answer nonetheless (+1).

Comment: @axiom Thanks. `Iterator` because this is the signature of `mapPartitions*` so `List` won't do it. Regarding `first` vs `min`... I thought about it and there is a subtle trade-off here. `first` works great if we can stop search on the first partition. Otherwise it will try to iterate increasing number of partitions to take each time and each iteration starts separate job. Depending on a cluster a data you can get lower latency by processing everything and taking min But is more a naive heuristic than anything else. And probably premature optimization :)

Comment: @axiom Regarding order this should work just fine as long as input RDD itself has roughly deterministic order. This of course not always the case but I assume that OP is aware of that.